# Invalid value around character 0 swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I hope you are having a great day. I encountered an error that I did some research about. The error I think means that my JSON object is not a proper one to be serialized by the JSONSerialization class on swift 3.0. I verified that my json object is not valid by using the method .isValidJSONObject of the JSONSerialization class.

I checked that my json object is valid. The error occure at the line where "JSONSerialization.jsonObject" method execute. I would love if you can help me figure out how to solve this problem. Feel free to ask for more code parts or project settings. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code used:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
    lazy var receivedData = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost:8080/OurServer/webresources/server")!
        var request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request as URLRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection.start()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive data: Data)
    {
        receivedData.append(data)
        var temp1 = receivedData as NSMutableData
        do
        {
            var temp3 = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(receivedData)
                var jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: receivedData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            print("\n")
            print(jsonResult)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("\n" + "\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: copy your json response and post it in this webSite https://jsonlint.com/ and validate it, must have some error

Comment: Add an example of your JSON.

Comment: Don't know if I understood, but you know your json is not valid and you are trying to solve it via swift code ?

Comment: *Invalid value around character 0* simply means you got an empty string. And do not use `NS...` and `NSMutable...` classes in Swift if there is a mutable native counterpart (`URLRequest`, `Data`).

Comment: @ReinierMelian just validated that it is a correct json

Comment: @Bryan {"course":"Mobile Programming","marks":"90"}

Comment: @vadian Can you please explain to me more what you meant, we can go on another chatting app if stacksoverflow does not support it. Chatting requires reputation points in stacksoverflow i guess

Comment: @ReinierMelian check my 2nd comment to verify the json.

Comment: Basically you should deserialize the JSON in `didFinishLoading` rather than in `didReceiveData`. Anyway `NSURLConnection` is outdated,   I recommend `URLSession` and `dataTask` using the block based API

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment `NSURLConnection` is outdated.

This is a modern, Swift 3 compliant version of your code using `URLSession`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/OurServer/webresources/server")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
                print("\n", jsonResult)
            } catch {
                print("\n", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not see your full method names cause they were covered by 3 dots if they were long

Comment: I mean all relevant methods starting with `NS` and with `NSMutable`. There is `URL`, `URLRequest`, `Error`, `Data` and `[String:Any]` in Swift 3 instead of `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest`, `NSError`, `NSMutableData` and `NSDictionary`

Comment: I did some updates to your code since the compiler showed some errors. It still gives me the same error though. I mostly using your code with minor updates

Comment: Then – once again – you are receiving an empty string (no data). Do you get any JSON data when pasting the URL in a browser?

Comment: yes, I get data from browser in the json format that I posted, I still get the same error though

Comment: the error occurs after task.resume. Finding it strange why the error won't fire before. like when the method is executing

Comment: the dataTask method

Comment: Print the data you are receiving, the first byte must be `7B`

Comment: There could be an invisible control character at the beginning, you can prove it by printing the `Data` bytes. By the way: What errors do you get in my code? This code is supposed to compile without errors.

Comment: I applied a method in java since my restFul webservice in java. the method removes any white space. a Json deserializer should scan a string by delimiter of \" by default. I will let you knoe about the error that I got after a while buddy. I am just focusing on solving this problem for now

Comment: if you could wait, unless if you want to know the error now. I can send you the successfully compiled code when i finish solving it

Comment: i'll check something and let u know buddy, u r busy?

Answer (score 0):

After checking, it appears i made a not very smart mistake. The mistake was with my url. excuse me for that guys.